# SSRS Dynamically Show Data

Tags: ssrs-2012, show-hide, reportbuilder, drilldown

I am wondering if you can have other tables show based on the value selected in the main table.  I am not opposed to drill-down either.

My main table is the summary and was hoping to show additional data when the user clicks on a Type.  When clicked another table would be visible.  For example, in the screenshot, the Pool table would be visible when the Pool type is clicked in the main report.  As mentioned if this is easier as a drill-down then I will do that, but not sure how.  The report currently has a dataset for each table.  Do I need to combine the datasets to do a drill-down?

[Main and child tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyHuD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to accomplish what you described is with a drill down and you would need to combine the datasets into one.

1. Combine your datasets
2. Add a table to your report and reference the single dataset
3. Add your detail row group to the table - from your child table (**Area, Average**)
4. Add a parent group to your details row, group your detail row group by **Type**, it should add a Type column to your table. Delete this column and it will ask you to delete the associated group as well. Select the option to delete only the column.
   [image: Delete Column]
5. Recreate your table by adding rows, be sure to match the grouping indicators (brackets) on the left side 
   [image: Main Table]
6. Right-Click on the bottom row in the box where the bracket is to highlight the entire row, click **Row Visibility**. For the option "when the report is initially run:", select **Hide**. Check "Display can be toggled by this report item" and select the name of the textbox that contains [Type]. If you don't know what this is, exit out of the dialogue box and right-click on the cell [Type] and click Textbox properties, the **Name** will be in there
7. Repeat step 6 for the label row for your details row (second row from the bottom)